# Why is my client saying "A fatal error occured. Bitcoin can no longer continue safely and will quit. "?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

i am running bitcoin client on OSX. I am by no stretch of the imagination any good at using terminal. I had over 300 btc in there and my computer went black and now client keeps giving me this message "A fatal error occured. Bitcoin can no longer continue safely and will quit.

EXCEPTION: 22DbRunRecoveryException
DbEnv::open: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
bitcoin in Runaway exception
"
I can pay somebody to help me fix this problem. dont want to lose the coins i have there. thanks. you'll have to bear with me though. not too good at this.

Comment: If you don't already have a backup of your `wallet.dat` file, make one now. If you do already have one, make another but don't overwrite the old one with this one. So long as you have some file that contains your private keys, you will ultimately be able to recover the coins.

Comment: And be cautious if you proceed to hire someone to help.

Answer (score 2):

That alone doesn't provide enough information to know which database file the error is occurring with.   The debug.log might give a more precise indication.

If it is a problem with the blockchain, that is easily resolved.  If the problem occurred after your computer crashed, that is likely what happened.

First though check to eliminate that the problem is that your hard drive partition is filled with no disk space remaining.  That probably isn't the case on your Mac, but just in case, check first.

So, after making yet another backup up your wallet.dat, then you can do this to get a new copy of the blockchain:

These instructions are for mac.  For Linux and Windows the [directory](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory#Default_Location) names would be different.

```
 $ cd ~/Library/Application Support 
 $ mv Bitcoin Bitcoin-bak
 $ mkdir Bitcoin
 $ cd Bitcoin
 $ cp ../Bitcoin-bak/wallet.dat .
```

Then launch Bitcoin-Qt as normal.  It will re-download the blockchain.  This could take 24 hours or more, depending on a number of factors.

You might speed that up a bit by getting the blockchain as-of block 170,000 from here:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/blockchain

After it downloads, extract those files into your new ~/.bitcoin directory.

If after Bitcoin-qt downloads the blockchain to the most recent block and everything works fine (shows your wallet balance and transactions properly), you can then remove the .bitcoin-bak directory:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Application Support 
$ rm -rf Bitcoin-bak
```

Also, the blockchain download is faster if you are on the most recent release of Bitcoin-Qt, v0.6.3.

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that I cannot even find the wallet.dat file. like i previously stated I am a complete novice and cannot navigate terminal well at all. I am following what i have read as best i can and keep getting terminal messages that say there is no such file.

Comment: but i would like to say thank you to you guys thus far. really appreciate it

Comment: Oops, I had the wrong directory names, ... Mac is different.  Updated the post.  Try again please.

Comment: Also, I added a note about the disk space.  Just check that the disk isn't full -- that could cause this as well.

Comment: got terminal working. buuuuut it still doesnt think there is a wallet.dat file: miltons-MacBook-Pro:Bitcoin milton$ cd ~/Library /Application Support
miltons-MacBook-Pro:Library milton$ mv Bitcoin Bitcoin-bak
miltons-MacBook-Pro:Library milton$ mkdir Bitcoin
miltons-MacBook-Pro:Library milton$ cd Bitcoin
miltons-MacBook-Pro:Bitcoin milton$ cp ~/Bitcoin-bak/wallet.dat .
cp: /Users/milton/Bitcoin-bak/wallet.dat: No such file or directory
miltons-MacBook-Pro:Bitcoin milton$

Comment: thanks again for all th help. still havent fixed it but i think i am on the right path, as everything worked except the last command line

Comment: Sorry, fixed my typo.  Try this:

  $ cd ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin

then

  $ cp ../Bitcoin-bak/wallet.dat .

Comment: should i try these two command lines after, $ cd ~/Library/Application Support 
 $ mv Bitcoin Bitcoin-bak
 $ mkdir Bitcoin
 $ cd Bitcoin

Comment: I'm sorry, stack exchange comments suck as far as communicating.  If you'ld like further assistance, please request help in the #bitcoin IRC channel: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#bitcoin