# Bitcoin client fails and reports some database recovery error

Tags: client, bitcoin-core, database

I am looking for somebody to help me fix my Bitcoin client, it is corrupt, reads :

```
"A fatal error occured. Bitcoin can no longer continue safely and will quit.
EXCEPTION: 22DbRunRecoveryException       
DbEnv::open: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery       
bitcoin in Runaway exception "
```

Have tried and tried to no avail to fix the damned thing and am at the point that I would like to pay someone to fix it for me.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If the problem is with the blockchain, the problem can be fixed easily.  If the problem is with wallet.dat the problem can range from trivial to impossible. 

Even if your wallet.dat is corrupted, if you have a backup up wallet.dat, it likely holds all the private keys necessary to recover the funds.

Comment: Here's history on this: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4703/153 It could just be the blockchain that is hosed. The user is not technical and thus why steps that would likely have resolved this haven't already been performed.

Comment: Would a solution be for someone to import your wallet.dat into BlockChain.info/wallet, and then you can access it and transact there?

That's an hour or less of work from someone, the problem is just that you'ld want someone trustworthy.

Comment: Your best best is probably to ask for help in the IRC channel, as Stephen Gornick mentioned here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4703/516 but the trustworthyness issue is important to consider